# Does the Jira Software backup manager export folder expire after 7 days even if it is saved on your computer?

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

I am creating a backup (for cloud) of my Jira Software using the "Backup Manager." The description says that "This backup file will replace the previous backup and will be automatically deleted after 7 days."

Does this mean that if I try to import this zip folder to a Jira url after 7 days, the import will be unsuccessful? Will the files in the zip folder expire after 7 days even though I have downloaded the backup on my hard drive?

Please advise.